# Computing the area of a complex (self-intersecting) polygon

Tags: polygon, area, processing.js, triangulation

I'm making a program that selects an area within a canvas by clicking a sequence of points. The points clicked are linked by some lines this way: every new point is linked with the first and the last ones. I'm looking for an algorithm that computes the area of the resulting polygon.

Intersections are allowed, and here is the complexity, so the algorithm must manage this case by finding the polygon according to the ordered sequence of points clicked and calculating its area.

After many searches, the best I've found is this http://sigbjorn.vik.name/projects/Triangulation.pdf, but I would need something easier to implement in Processing.js.

Answer (score 0):

First cut the line segments where they intersect. If the input set is small, you can simply check every pair. Otherwise use an R-Tree. Then compute a constrained (Delaunay) Triangulation. Then determine the inner triangles using rayshooting and sum up their areas.

hth

Comment: Finally I've decided to simplify the problem not allowing intersections. Thanks anyway.